# User Definition in Team Foundation Server (TFS)

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a question about user definition in TFS. Should I create a new user account for everyone that want to work in my team in TFS Server?

In sourcesafe or subversion, it did not need to create a user on its server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should create account either on a server itself or in a domain this server belongs to. "By design security for Team Foundation is integrated with Windows authentication and based on users and groups," - from this [MSDN reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms253147.aspx).

By the way, it is recommended not to give permissions for a particular user, but rather assign permissions to groups and then just add users to those groups.